# PHPBB3 How to display Last Post Title in index

Tags: php, templates, phpbb3

I am using the prosilver theme in phpbb3. In the file `forumlist_body.html` there is a part that looks like this:

```
<dd class="lastpost"><span>
<!-- IF forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME -->
<dfn>{L_LAST_POST}</dfn> {L_POST_BY_AUTHOR} {forumrow.LAST_POSTER_FULL}
  <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT -->
  <a href="{forumrow.U_LAST_POST}">{LAST_POST_IMG}</a>
  <!-- ENDIF -->
<br />
{forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME}
<!-- ELSE -->{L_NO_POSTS}<br />
<!-- ENDIF -->
</span></dd>
```

How would I get that to show the last post title as well. I tried `{forumrow.LAST_POST_TITLE}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

{forumrow.LAST_POST_SUBJECT} is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

its simple ,,

i have made those modifications ,,

here is the code just replace :

```
<dd class="lastpost"><span>
                    <!-- IF forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_TOPICS --><a href="{forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_TOPICS}">{UNAPPROVED_IMG}</a><!-- ENDIF -->
                     <!-- IF forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME -->{forumrow.LAST_POST_SUBJECT}&nbsp;&nbsp; {L_POST_BY_AUTHOR} {forumrow.LAST_POSTER_FULL}
                    <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT --><a href="{forumrow.U_LAST_POST}">{LAST_POST_IMG}</a> <!-- ENDIF --><br />{forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME}<!-- ELSE -->{L_NO_POSTS}<br />&nbsp;<!-- ENDIF --></span>
                </dd>
                <dd class="topics">{forumrow.TOPICS}<br /><span>{L_TOPICS}</span><dfn>{L_TOPICS}</dfn></dd>
                <dd class="posts">{forumrow.POSTS}<br /><span>{L_POSTS}</span><dfn>{L_POSTS}</dfn></dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like mine..

```
*

  {forumrow.FORUM_NAME}{L_FORUM}
      {L_TOPICS}
      {L_POSTS}
      {L_LAST_POST}

*

  {forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE} {forumrow.FORUM_NAME}
  {forumrow.FORUM_DESC}
  {forumrow.L_MODERATOR_STR}: {forumrow.MODERATORS}
  {forumrow.L_SUBFORUM_STR} {forumrow.SUBFORUMS}
      {L_REDIRECTS}: {forumrow.CLICKS}
      {forumrow.TOPICS} {L_TOPICS}
      {forumrow.POSTS} {L_POSTS}
      {L_LAST_POST}{L_POST_BY_AUTHOR}{forumrow.LAST_POSTER_FULL}  {LAST_POST_IMG}
      {forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME}{L_NO_POSTS}
```

{L_NO_FORUMS}